# Run Django Application in Apache Server (Ubuntu) with the SSL connection

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment

The Apache Server is by default locating the `www/html` folder with `port:8080` (default was: 80).
Now Django files are kept in html/django are running with port:80
It is running http://example.com

Now after adding SSL the `www/html/django` is showing all the file structure. when running https://example.com

Nowt getting any Solution how to work with same

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

Already changed in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/django.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    #My site Name
    ServerName example.com


    SSLEngine on


    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-c.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-c.key


    #Demon process for multiple virtual hosts
    WSGIDaemonProcess example.com threads=5

    #Pointing wsgi script to config file
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/django/django.wsgi
    WSGIProcessGroup example.com

    #Your static files location
    Alias /static/ "/var/www/html/django/template/"
    <Location "/media">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>
    <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
        SetHandler None
    </LocationMatch>
    <Directory /var/www/html/django>
        WSGIProcessGroup example.com
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way I do this is by creating two `.conf` files, and avoid overwriting the stock `httpd.conf`. First, an `ssl.conf` file:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-c.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-c.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/private/InCommonRSAServerCA_2.pem
SSLCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

Listen 443
```

This will disable insecure, older protocols and require TLS 1.2+.

Then I create a file for each site I'm hosting on the server as a `VirtualHost`, for example, `mysite.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost my-site.example.com:80>
  ServerName my-site.example.com
  ServerAlias www.my-site.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://my-site.example.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  TimeOut 600
  SSLEngine On

  ServerName my-site.example.com
  ServerAlias www.my-site.example.com

  # Set to the lobal Application Group
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  # Pass Authorizations through to the WSGI app for Django REST Framework Token Auth
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  WSGIDaemonProcess my-site-https python-home=/var/django/my-site/sites/my-site/venv request-timeout=600 user=apache group=apache processes=1
  WSGIProcessGroup my-site-https
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/my-site/sites/my-site/config/wsgi.py process-group=my-site-https
  <Directory /var/django/my-site/sites/my-site/config>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /static/ /var/django/my-site/sites/my-site/static/
  <Directory /var/django/my-site/sites/my-site/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There are a few extra things here. First, `WSGIPassAuthorization` is turned on, in case you're using Django REST Framework token auth. You may not need this.

`WSGIDaemonProcess` contains several explicit settings you may want to change or not need, such as `user`, `group`, and `processes`. This allows you to tune what user and group the Apache Linux process for this `VirtualHost` runs as, and `processes` controls how many processes to have.

The two `Directory` directives are needed to allow access to your Django project's `.wsgi` configuration file, and your static files.

Good luck! It is tricky to configure, but once you get it right, `mod_wsgi` is rock solid.